# How do I convert a UE4 FString into a string?

Tags: c++, string, unreal-engine4, data-conversion

`TextLine2` needs to be a regular string however I receive the error `no instance of constructor matches the argument list.`

```
void AAH_Ver1_2::GetEachTextFromLine(FString TextLine1)
{
    string TextLine2 = TextLine1;
    istringstream iss(TextLine2);
}
```

Comment: Did you try googling "ue4 fstring to string"? answers.unrealengine.com has a number of topics explaining what Fstring is and how it is converted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert an `FString` to an `std::string` with the `TCHAR_TO_UTF8` macro:

```
std::string const s = TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*fstring);
```